# How do I define a template function within a template class outside of the class definition?

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <class U>
    void bar();
};
```

How do I implement bar outside of the class definition while still having access to both template parameters T and U?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

IIRC:

```
template<class T> template <class U>
void Foo<T>::bar() { ...
```

Comment: And I still don't understand why `template<class T, class U> void Foo<T>::bar(){...}` won't work...

Comment: @Xeo its two separate templates, class and function.  (i think thats why)

Comment: @Xeo because it's `Foo<T>::bar<U>`, not `Foo<T,U>::bar`