# How to define a template member function of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I define a template function within a template class outside of the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class)

I'm struggling with the syntax for the case where I have a template member function within a template class:

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
    void Bar(const T * t);
    template <typename T2> void Bar(const T2 * t);
};

template <typename T> void Foo<T>::Bar(const T * t)
{
    // ... no problem ...
}

template <typename T> void Foo<T>::Bar<typename T2>(const T2 * t)
{
    // ... this is where I'm tearing my hair out ...
}
```

The first member function is fine, but the template member function which handles types other than the base type of the template class is where I am having problems. For the above case I get the following errors:

```
template_problem.cpp:12: error: parse error in template argument list
template_problem.cpp:12: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
template_problem.cpp:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘T2’ with no type
template_problem.cpp:12: error: template-id ‘Bar<<expression error> >’ in declaration of primary template
template_problem.cpp:12: error: prototype for ‘void Foo<T>::Bar(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Foo<T>’
template_problem.cpp:4: error: candidates are: template<class T> template<class T2> void Foo::Bar(const T2*)
template_problem.cpp:7: error:                 void Foo<T>::Bar(const T*)
template_problem.cpp:12: error: template definition of non-template ‘void Foo<T>::Bar(int)’
```

and I've also tried every other syntax variation I can think of for the template version of `Bar`.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
void Foo<T>::Bar(const T2* t) 
{
     // stop tearing your hair out
}
```

Comment: Can the lines `template<typename T>` and `template<typename T2>` change places?

Comment: @hkBattousai If you change `Foo<T>` to `Foo<T2>`, then yes. The order matters.

Comment: Why is it necessary to define a class template function as void Foo<T>::Bar() instead of void Foo::Bar()? What's the reason for adding <T> to the Foo(class name)? Why not the plain Foo(class name)?

Comment: @Rahul because it's a template class and requires a template argument.

Answer (score 11):

```
template <typename T>
template <typename T2> 
void Foo<T>::Bar(const T2 * t) {
    // ... this is where I'm tearing my hair out ...
}
```

Ugly isn't it.

Comment: Yes - it's amazing how many different and seemingly logical syntax variations you can try without stumbling on the correct one.

Comment: @PaulR to be honest for templates it becomes such a tangle that I write the implementations right in the class definition. I honestly believe that is easy to read then all separated out with the template junk added to it.

Comment: Yes - I'm beginning to see the attraction of doing it that way.