# Getting LNK2001 error while using template member functions

Tags: c++

So im getting unresolved external and im confused why its not linking properly

memory.cpp: https://pastebin.com/x284CFTt

memory.hpp: https://pastebin.com/9xNcVY9q

main.cpp: https://pastebin.com/hQFTmn8E

Output Window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NAME, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>memory.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Memory::Write<int>(unsigned __int64,int)" (??$Write@H@Memory@@QAE_N_KH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Memory::Read<int>(unsigned __int64)" (??$Read@H@Memory@@QAEH_K@Z)
1>D:\Desktop\Workbench\NAME\bin\x86_Release\NAME.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "NAME.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why its giving me these errors.. Im so confused, ive done properly the class templates i think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a member function template of a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394832/how-to-define-a-template-member-function-of-a-template-class). Usually the easiest thing to do is use [#include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and put the implementation with the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler needs both template class/function declaration and definition to create template class/function of specific types (`int` in your case).

There are the following possible solutions:

1. Add both template declaration and definition to the header file.
2. Add explicit template instantiation for each type to template source file. In your case add the following lines to `memory.cpp`

`template int Memory::Read(DWORD64 Address);`

`template bool Memory::Write(DWORD64 Address, int dataBuffer);`

3. Include template source file `memory.cpp` to `main.cpp`. However i think that's not a nice solution.

Comment: for solution number 2 Do i really have to make explicit template instantiation for every possible type ?

Comment: Also is it a good practice if i make the whole class definition in the .hpp file?

Comment: Yes, if you use explicit template instantiation you have to do it for each type you are using. This is why a header-only solution is good and common practice. It's more flexible and a lot of libraries using templates do it this way.