# Defining out-of-line member template functions

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, member-functions

Consider this (minimized) example:

```
template <typename Descriptor>
class hash_table
{
public:
  typedef int value_type;

  template <typename Argument, int Callback (value_type *, Argument)>
  void traverse (Argument);

  template <int Callback (value_type *)>
  void traverse_void ();
};
```

I defined a class template which has template member functions with non-type parameters. Note that `Callback` depends on `value_type` typedef. Now I want to define the functions themselves:

```
template <typename Descriptor>
template <typename Argument, int Callback (typename hash_table <Descriptor>::value_type *, Argument)>
void hash_table <Descriptor>::traverse (Argument) {}

template <typename Descriptor>
template <int Callback (typename hash_table <Descriptor>::value_type *)>
void hash_table <Descriptor>::traverse_void () {}
```

I get inconsistent errors from the compilers. The result does not depend on options, specifying the version of C++ standard (i.e., same for C++98, C++11 and C++14), but depends on the compiler.

GCC 6.0.0 (recent trunk, as well as several other versions) accepts this code.

Clang 3.7.0 (recent trunk) gives the following error:

```
test.cc:18:31: error: out-of-line definition of 'traverse_void' does not match any declaration in 'hash_table<Descriptor>'
void hash_table <Descriptor>::traverse_void() {}
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

EDG (Intel C++ Compiler v. 15.0.3) gives two errors:

```
test.cc(15): error: declaration is incompatible with function template "void hash_table<Descriptor>::traverse<Argument,Callback>(Argument)" (declared at line 7)
  void hash_table <Descriptor>::traverse (Argument) {}
                                ^

test.cc(19): error: declaration is incompatible with function template "void hash_table<Descriptor>::traverse_void<Callback>()" (declared at line 10)
  void hash_table <Descriptor>::traverse_void () {}
                                ^
compilation aborted for test.cc (code 2)
```

What is the expected behavior (according to the standard)? If the code is wrong, how do I fix the function definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define a template function within a template class outside of the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, I see no reason for it to not compile. Probably a bug on the compilers that disallow it. However, since [temp.param]:

> A non-type *template-parameter* of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be of type
>   “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`”, respectively.

You could simply switch `Callback` yourself to be a pointer-to-function. The behavior would be identical in all respects, with the added benefit that this code also compiles on clang.

Comment: [temp.param]/p8. There's an automatic adjustment similar to function parameters.

Comment: @T.C. That is horribly worded then. What's the point of enumerating the allowed types if you're going to add more later?