# c++ Error 'template<class T> class List' used without template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am facing an error when using a template. I am not familiar with the concept of `template` but I am studying with the help of a book, and the code is from the book. However, when I execute my code, I get errors like this. Can you help me, and why this error can occur?

My code is like this:

```
template <class T>
class List{
    private:
        Node<T> *dummyHead;
    public:
        ... // I have another methods in here
        void insert(const T& data, Node<T>* p);
        .... // I have another methods in here
};

template <class T>
void List::insert(const T& data, Node<T>* p) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data, p->next);
    p->next = newNode;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `insert` logic looks a bit weird. Is the second argument `p` a "parent" node where you want to insert a new node? Classic approach is just to have `void insert(const T& data);` and appending the new node to the last node already in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I define a template function within a template class outside of the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class)

Comment: Exactly, p is a "parent" node. Yes, this answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the template parameter to your `List`:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insert(const T& data, Node<T>* p) {
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(data,p->next);
    p->next=newNode;
}
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template) for the out of class member function definition syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the documentation. I understood now.