# C++ compiling definitions of member functions of template classes in separate files

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

This is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class) question, I can compile my member function definition. What I want to do is have the definitions of my member functions in one file, which is compiled separately from the files where I use them.

As an example, I want to create a template class `tensor` with a certain size `SIZE`. The header file `tensor.hpp` could look like this:

```
#pragma once

#include<cstdint>

template <uint64_t SIZE>class tensor
{
private:
    //SIMPLIFIED example with no data
public:
    tensor();
};
```

Really it will contain a lot more data and member functions, but that isn't needed to demonstrate this.

In another file `main.cpp`, I might want to use a `tensor<2>`, for example, I might just call the constructor:

```
#include "tensor.cpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tensor<2> g;//Call one particular constructor

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I need the definition to exist, for every member function of `tensor<SIZE>` I call, these member functions can be defined like this:

```
#include "tensor.hpp"

template <uint64_t SIZE>
    tensor<SIZE>::tensor()
    {/*Example, empty constructor*/}
```

Normally (if I wasn't using templates) I would put that in a separate file `tensor.cpp`, which I would compile separately from `main.cpp`, and then link together like this:

```
g++ -c main.o main.cpp -std=c++17
g++ -c tensor.o tensor.cpp -std=c++17
g++ -o program.a tensor.o main.o -std=c++17
```

But that  doesn't work when compiling `tensor.cpp` the compiler doesn't know that I will later need the `SIZE=2` version of `tensor`, so the member functions for that are not defined, and I get a linker error on the last line:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `tensor<2ul>::tensor()'
```

I know I can get around this by just including the definition directly in my `tensor.hpp` file. But I do know ahead of time what versions of the template class I need, for example, I might know that I need `tensor<1>` up to `tensor<5>`.

So is there any way I can tell the compiler, that it needs to generate the requisite definitions when compiling `tensor.cpp`?

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: In particular, there's "Alternative solution" section in the accepted answer to that question.