# How can I achieve an template method in a template class detached?

Tags: c++, templates

I can make a code like this, it worked:

```cpp
//template class
template<T>
class TemplateClass{
public:
  void print();
}
template<T>
void TemplateClass<T>::print(){ return; }

//template function
class Print{
public:
  template<class T>
  void TemplateFunction();
}

template<class T>
Print::TemplateFunction(){ return; }
```

But how can I make this worked as similar?

```cpp
//template class and function
class TemplateClass{
public:
  template<class T>
  void TemplateFunction();
}

template<class T, class T1>
TemplateClass<T>::TemplateFunction(){ return; }
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Your `TemplateClass` in the last example is not a template! I suppose that is a typo. See [How do I define a template function within a template class outside of the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class)

Comment: when you declare the method template to have 1 template argument you cannot define it with 2 template arguments. It is unclear what you want to "make work". And it looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details.

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question. I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: and complete code. `TemplateClass` is not a template in your second example. The comment says it would be but it isnt